# How can I get the "Watched Tags" to override the "Ignored Tags"?

Tags: support, tags

I have a number of watched tags, such as "causality", "confounding", and "regression". I have one ignored tag, "R", since I am not an "R" person. However, if a question is tagged both with "R" and with "confounding", say, the question appears in light font, just as it would if it didn't have the "confounding" tag. I would prefer my watched tags to override the ignored tags, so that those questions show up in tan with regular fonts.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is a general SE system issue, so it may be better to ask on [meta.SE].

Comment: I am not an R person either, and no criticism either way. But ignoring the R tag in practice just means ignoring many, many posts that have an R tag only because the poster is using R. In fact if a post is more than incidentally about R it is likely to be off-topic any way....